# How to remove uninstalled DLL from SxS cache

Tags: windows, side-by-side, winsxs, sxs

I had VS 2008.  I upgraded to VS 2010, and uninstalled VS 2008.

I have a test that runs on my machine, but fails to load on machines in the build lab.  After some debugging, I realized that the test executable still had a dependency on msvcr90d.dll (which is a VC++ 2008 debug runtime library).  Even though I had uninstalled VS 2008, the test works on my machine because that runtime DLL still exists in the side-by-side cache (%windir%/winsxs).  The build lab machine doesn't have the DLL, so it won't load there.

Shouldn't uninstalling VS 2008 have caused all of its runtime DLLs to be removed from the side-by-side cache?

Is there a way I can manually remove these old DLLs from the side-by-side cache?  I'd like to be able to easily detect other places where I might still have an out-of-date dependency.

Comment: @Hans Passant:  Even after elevating to administrator, I get a dialog saying I cannot delete system files.  "You need permission to perform this action[.]  You require permission from SYSTEM to make changes to this file[.]"

Comment: Erm, wait, what *exact* file are you trying to delete.  Post the full path.

Comment: @Hans: Just deleting from winsxs would be a bad idea.

Comment: Exact path:  C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_bb1f6aa1308c35eb\msvcr90d.dll

Comment: You seem to be persuing the course that means the app runs nowhere. Surely you need to fix the dependency.

Comment: @David: I did fix the dependency.  My point is I want to be able to detect other bad dependencies on my machine.  I want any app that still has that dependency to fail, so that I know about it and can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to take ownership of the containing folder. All the folders there will be owned by SYSTEM or TrustedInstaller. So do this:

Right click->Properties->Security tab->Advanced->Owner tab->Edit->Select yourself as owner->tick 'Replace owner on subcontainers and objects->OK

Once you've done that, you can do Right click->Properties->Security tab->Give yourself full control->OK

Or if you're familiar with the cacls command you can do it from the command line.

Once you've got full control you can move the folder, which I highly recommend over deleting it.  Deleting files from winsxs is likely to break other applications or even Windows.